# AJAX request posts on second submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

I was making a form to post data, combined with Ajax. Below is all code associated with it. The problem is that when filling the form in and submitting, on the first click it does the XHR request, and get's a success call back so changes the button to Done!.

But the results don't appear in the database. When clicking the submit button again, it does another XHR request that DOES get through. Any ideas what  could cause this? Thanks!

```
// Method for updating the post in User.php
    public function updatePost($id, $title, $content){
            $query1 = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE posts SET post_title=:post_title, post_content=:post_content WHERE post_id=:post_id");
            $query1->bindparam(":post_title", $title);
            $query1->bindparam(":post_content", $content);
            $query1->bindparam(":post_id", $id);
            try {
                $query1->execute();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

        } ?>
// Backend for the authenication and validation (where the form posts to)
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once("../User.php");
    $login = new User();
    $errors = [];
    $post_title = $_POST['post-title'];
    $post_content = $_POST['post-content'];
    $post_id = $_POST['post-id'];

    if( isset($post_title) && isset($post_content) && isset($post_id) ){
        if( empty($post_title) ){
            $errors[] = "The entered title is invalid in some way.";
        }
        elseif (empty($post_content)) {
            $errors[] = "The entered content is invalid in some way.";
        }
        elseif(empty($post_id)){
            $errors[] = "An internal error has occured, please contact the system administrator.";
        }
        else{
            try {
                if( !$login->updatePost($post_id, $post_title, $post_content) ){
                    echo "allrighty";
                }
                else{
                    echo "charliewegotaproblem";
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

        }
    }

 ?>
// JS for the Ajax request itself
$("form").submit(function(evt){
    evt .preventDefault();
    var url         = $(this).attr("action");
    var formData    = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax(url, {
        data: formData,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(response){
            if(response == "allrighty"){
                $(".update-submit").prop("value", "Done!")
            }
            else if (response == "charliewegotaproblem") {
                $(".update-submit").prop("value", "Something went wrong...")
            }
        }
    }); // Ajax OBJECT END;
});// Submit END
```

Comment: What is expected behaviour? Update database using ajax on first click or submit the `form` on second click? What is doing `!$login->updatePost($post_id, $post_title, $post_content)`?

Comment: It is updating a post in a database, which is later retrieved (CMS). It is supposed to update the database with the altered post. This happends but on second click (it does update the button text on first click, which should only happend if the method runs succesfully and outputs "allrighty") Which is not the case.

Comment: !$login->updatePost($post_id, $post_title, $post_content) is the method that updates the database (See top of code post) (EDIT: updated to correct method)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
```

==> First return success message, if post update query has executed successfully in updatePost function

```
// Method for updating the post in User.php
public function updatePost($id, $title, $content){
    $success = false;            // Here I changed the code 
        $query1 = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE posts SET post_title=:post_title, post_content=:post_content WHERE post_id=:post_id");
        $query1->bindparam(":post_title", $title);
        $query1->bindparam(":post_content", $content);
        $query1->bindparam(":post_id", $id);
        try {
            $query1->execute();
    if($query1){ $success = true; }      // Here I changed the code 
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    return $success;
    }
```

==> Now here if $login has return true than an only than "allrighty" will return

```
// Backend for the authenication and validation (where the form posts to)

session_start();
require_once("../User.php");
$login = new User();
$errors = [];
$post_title = $_POST['post-title'];
$post_content = $_POST['post-content'];
$post_id = $_POST['post-id'];

if( isset($post_title) && isset($post_content) && isset($post_id) ){
    if( empty($post_title) ){
        $errors[] = "The entered title is invalid in some way.";
    }
    elseif (empty($post_content)) {
        $errors[] = "The entered content is invalid in some way.";
    }
    elseif(empty($post_id)){
        $errors[] = "An internal error has occured, please contact the system administrator.";
    }
    else{
        try {
            if($login->updatePost($post_id, $post_title, $post_content)){    // Here I changed the code 
                echo "allrighty";
            }
            else{
                echo "charliewegotaproblem";
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Didn't work. This changes the way the back-end handles it, but result is still the same. I need to submit the form twice before it posts data. I thought someting was wrong with the javascript, but can't find any flaws..